# Remove characters between backslashes in string in Python

Tags: python, regex

Is this the correct way to remove everything between two backward slashes?

```
clean = re.sub(r'\\.+?\\', '', clean)
```

Example input:

```
a\ue00f\ue010\ue011\ue012\ue013\a
```

Example output:

```
aa
```

Comment: These are backslashes not forward slashes.

Comment: Are the things like `\ue00f` literally that or are they Unicode characters?

Comment: I would assume literally, how else could they be replaced?

Comment: Well, does it work? (My guess: No, because it is non-greedy, because of your `?` after the plus. Remove that and it'll be greedy.)

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: I don't think that that's a fair assumption. The OP is probably looking at `repr()` output and not understanding that the `\uhhhh` escape sequences are really single Unicode codepoints that are not printable. That needs to be clarified before the question is answerable.

Comment: Yes, I was implying such a notion with the phrase how else.

Comment: For example, printing `tokenize(myText)` was giving me output: `u'\ue000\ue001\ue002\...ue0e9\ue0ea\ue0eb\ue0ec\ue0ed\ue0ee\ue0ef\ue0f0\ue0f1\ue0f2\ue0f3\ue0f4\ue0f5\ue0f6\ue0f7\ue0f8\ue0f9\ue0fa\ue0fb\ue0fc\ue0fd\ue0fe\ue0ff', u'Elevated', u'plasminogen', u'activator'; `Clearly I'm after the 'Elevated', 'plasminogen', etc.

Comment: The `ue000` are certainly elements of the list returned by `tokenize()`, however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe split() can help here:

```
>>> input = r'a\ue00f\ue010\ue011\ue012\ue013\a'
>>> elems = input.split('\\')
>>> ''.join((elems[0], elems[-1]))
'aa'
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to just match anything between backward slashes and just replace it with nothing?

Comment: @Sam I'm not sure why there would be such a thing built into the language... but that's essentially what I'm doing. What's not helpful about the solution I've offered?